# How to pass two parameters in header using AT Command with SIM800 GSM modem?

Tags: web-services, gsm, rest-api

I have a restful webservice with POST method. I want to use this webservice using a GSM Modem with SIM800.

I am using following command instruction:

```
AT+SAPBR=2,1   --Check if bearer 1 is open or not
AT+SAPBR=1,1   --Enable bearer 1
AT+HTTPINIT
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","myWebserviceURL"
AT+HTTPPARA="CONTENT","application/json"
AT+HTTPDATA=82,10000
  OK
  DOWNLOAD
[mY_dATA_GOES_HERE]
AT+HTTPACTION=1  --POST METHOD
AT+HTTPREAD
So far it works good.
```

Now I've two parameters in my Headers as in POSTMAN webservice Tool. `key=CONTENT-TYPE; value= application/json` and `key=AuthenticationToken; value=myAutoGeneratedCustomKey`. How do I add the second parameter using AT Command?

Answer (score 5):

As per [SIM800 AT command Manual](http://simcom.ee/documents/SIM800/SIM800%20Series_AT%20Command%20Manual_V1.10.pdf), you can set *`HTTPParamTag`* to *`USERDATA`* and send content in *`HTTPParamValue`*. You can pack all key-value pairs into *`HTTPParamValue`* and parse to retrieve individual key-value pairs.

A example for SIM 800 HTTP POST with Authentication and signature may be found [here](http://www.embeddedadvice.com/t/sim-800-http-post-with-authentication-and-signature/1862) as well.